# Query Zendesk tickets by keyword using ZenDesk API

Tags: json, curl, zendesk

By running the following query I can get all the first 100 tickets from our Zendesk account

```
curl -u user@domain.com:pass https://subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json > tickets.json
```

However, I would like to get tickets with keyword 'Tom'.  The keyword should appear in either the collaborators field or text data.

Is there a way to use the Zendesk API to query Zendesk tickets based on a keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
search.json?query=Tom
```

OR

```
search.json?query=type:user "Tom*"
```

See, if that helps.

Refer: [Link](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search)

Comment: Figured it out thanks to your prompt.  It should be search.json not tickets.json.  It works now, thanks!  Can you update your answer to search.json instead?

Comment: @joe Changed to search